# Bluetooth App Crashes with error FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: android, xml, logcat

My Bluetooth application's can already auto request to enable bluetooth but when I did some functionality on my option menu the application will crash right after the bluetooth was turned on.

These were the messages found in the LogCat:

```
12-21 15:20:08.531: D/BluetoothCommandService(1203): start
12-21 15:20:08.531: D/BluetoothCommandService(1203): setState() 0 -> 1
12-21 15:20:08.581: W/dalvikvm(1203): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40028870)
12-21 15:20:08.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1203): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-21 15:20:08.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1203): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-21 15:20:08.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at com.example.javac101.MainActivity$1.handleMessage(MainActivity.java:171)
12-21 15:20:08.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-21 15:20:08.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-21 15:20:08.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-21 15:20:08.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 15:20:08.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-21 15:20:08.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
12-21 15:20:08.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-21 15:20:08.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What would be the possible main cause of this errors?

Comment: line number **171** in `MainActivity.java` and also post that **java**

Comment: case BluetoothCommandService.stateNothing:
     title.setText(R.string.title_notConnected); //this is the line 171
break;

Comment: post your `MainActivity.java` and also check you have initilize your title `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

`title` might be null here.

Also change

```
title.setText(R.string.title_notConnected);
```

to

```
title.setText(getString(R.string.title_notConnected));
```